# Index out of range exception in asp.net

Tags: c#-4.0

while trying to connect to the database i have written the following code in my page load method :

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "select pid from pid";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(dt);
    a = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) + 1;
    con.Close();
    return a;
```

and i m getting an error in the code line    " a = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) + 1; "       as:
index out of range exception
there is no row at position 0
how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your query is returning no rows. Handle accordingly (if it's possible that the query returns no rows, add an `if` statement). Otherwise, perhaps something is amiss with your query (selecting a column from an object of the same name doesn't seem right).

```
int retVal = default( int );

if( dt.Rows.Count == 1 )
{
    retVal = (int)dt.Rows[0][columnName];
}

return retVal;
```

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "insert into Plist(Pid,passengername,flightid,Flightname,Fromstation,Tostation,category,Dateandtimings) values('" + Autonumber() + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.Text + "','" + DropDownList2.Text + "','" + DropDownList3.Text + "','" + DropDownList4.Text + "','" + DropDownList5.Text + "','" + DropDownList6.Text + "')";
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

error message:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Plist' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: That means you can't insert an explicit value into your identity column. Your insert statement is probably wrong.